# Answer with an image of my favorite musician

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, pattern, word-property

Here are several pictures of things that are NOT my favorite musician. The next picture was supposed to be him, but I deliberately did not upload it. Now it's up to you to guess :)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think your favourite musician is

> [image]
>  Stevie Wonder

So we have, in order,

> First Blush
>  [**Second** Wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_wind)
>  [**Third** Wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_Wheel)
>  [**Fourth** Wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_wall)
>  [**Fifth** Column](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth_column)
>  [**Sixth** Sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sixth_Sense)
>  [**Seventh** Heaven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seventh_Heaven)
>  so I guess next could be
>  [**Eighth** Wonder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eighth_Wonder_of_the_World)

Expanded Explanation

> For each n, the nth image represents the second word in a common phrase "nth ____".
>  The next image must therefore represent the second word in a phrase of the form "Eighth _____". There are a few possible candidates for this but "Eighth Wonder" is one that quickly springs to mind and is also the name of a famous musician.

Comment: That is correct! The first one was supposed to be rot13(svefg oyhfu), but this can't be found on Wikipedia. Your tick is shipped, arriving today in the evening.

Comment: Is my favorite musician too; but I couldn't understand how you find that. Can you explain it a little more, for the dummies like me?

Comment: @Koray I've added a paragraph with an expanded explanation. Hope this makes more sense.

Comment: (+1) Oh OK :) Thank you. I thought there was mathematical something that leads you to <surname> you've found.